# Create a Windows Explorer Context menu item to set a registry entry with the file path clicked

Tags: c#, windows, registry, contextmenu

I would like to create a Windows Explorer file Context menu item from C# to set a registry entry with the file path clicked, rather than run an executable. Whilst I can achieve this by writing a custom executable to receive the file path selected with the context menu and write it to the required Registry location I think there should be a neater way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a in-process [droptarget shell extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940354(v=vs.85).aspx) that does the work.

Answer (score 0):

The post at [Running a .bat file located in %AppData% from context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613513/running-a-bat-file-located-in-appdata-from-context-menu) contains an example of including a registry update directly from a Context Menu